${\cal N}=4$ Supersymmetric Yang-Mills
I am trying to calculate the beta function of SYM at 1-loop using brute calculation.
First of all, do you know if there are textbooks where explicit calculations are made?
I already recycled some 1-loop calculation from massless QCD, but i do not know what result i should expect in the end.
Secondly, i already look at articles linked to SYM and i suspect i can say something on its beta function without doing much calculations, “”simply”” using gauge invariance and susy invariance. I would as well try understanding this aspect.
I would appreciate your help…
Thank you for reading this, have a nice day

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269388912658 The beta function is expected to vanish at all orders. The theory is conformal at the quantum level.

SYM is basically just glorified QCD+Matter. You can literally take the QCD beta function formula from Wikipedia and apply it to SYM.
For a theory which has $n_s$ real scalars and $n_f$ Weyl fermions, all in the adjoint of the gauge group, the one-loop beta function is
$$
\beta_{1-loop}(g) = - C_2(G) \left( \frac{11}{3} - \frac{n_s}{6} - \frac{2n_f}{3} \right) \frac{g^3}{16\pi^2} 
$$
For SYM, we have $n_s=6$ and $n_f=4$, which implies $\beta_{1-loop}^{SYM}(g) = 0$.
For a derivation of the QCD beta function, you can look up any standard QFT textbook. For example, chapter 26 of Schwartz.
